# Проблема с JFileChooser

Tags: java

Выдержка из кода:

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();   
dialog.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
dialog.showSaveDialog(null);
if(dialog.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
try {
    File file = new File(dialog.getSelectedFile() + ".png");
    ImageIO.write(graphPanel.getImage(), "PNG", file);
}
catch(Exception ex){

}
```

проблема : открывает диалог сохранения, выбираем папку и вбиваем имя файла, жмем окей, и сразу открывается диалог открытия...

Comment: ну да, вы сначала делаете `showSaveDialog`, а потом `showOpenDialog`.

Comment: Работает так, как написано. Смотри 3-ю и 4-ю строки.

Answer (score 2):

Строку #3 удаляем, а в строке #4 меняем Open на Save

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?